# Why "It's better to use the bytes type instead of the bytes1[] type"? Solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, memory, bytes, documentation

I read a **Note** in documentation of Solidity:

> The type `bytes1[]` is an array of bytes, but due to padding
> rules, it wastes 31 bytes of space for each element (except in
> storage). It is better to use the `bytes` type instead.

I know that elements in memory always occupy multiples of 32 bytes, so each element of `bytes1[]` wastes 31 bytes. On the other hand, the `bytes` type is similar to `bytes1[]`, but it is packed tightly in calldata and memory. Therefore, `bytes` in memory can store data in the same way as it does in storage? Can somebody explain more details about the difference between `bytes` and `bytes1[]`?